# Isomorphic sets

Tags: order-theory

Consider $A=\mathbb{Z}\times \{1\}$ with the regular order of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=\mathbb{Q}\times\{2\}$  with the regular order of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Prove/disprove that $A+B$ is isomorphic to $B+A$.

I think that this theorem isn't true, but after some attempts, I have failed to prove it formally.

definition: Consider $(X,\leq_{X})$ and $(Y,\leq_{Y})$ with poset. $Y$ is isomorphic to $X$ if $f:X\to Y$ is isomorphism.

Comment: Isomorphic in which category?

Comment: and what is $+$?

Comment: $A+B$ and $B+A$ are the same set...

Comment: What is (a,1) + (b,2)?  How is A + B ordered?  Do you mean an order isomorphism?